# SET ERROR IGNORE Python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, instagram

I want set error ignore on my script if he don't find page instagram or xpath and continue script.

This is script:

import time
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
"GO INSTAGRAM PAGE FOR LOGIN"
browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?hl=it')

sleep(2)
"ID AND PASSWORD"

elem = browser.find_element_by_name("username").send_keys('id')

elem = browser.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys('pass')

"CLICK BUTTON AND OPEN INSTAGRAM"

sleep(5)

good_elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/article/div/div[1]/div/form/span/button').click()

sleep(5)

browser.get("https://www.instagram.com")

"GO TO PAGE FOR FOLLOW"

browser.get("https://www.instagram.com/test/")

time.sleep(5)

follow = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/header/section/div[1]/button').click()

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `set error ignore`? What is your _usecase_?

Comment: If don't find element by xpath i want script continue working.